# Codeigniter Ajax error communication error

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to check if username already exists in the table using ajax input onchange trigger in CodeIgnitor view.

Ajax function on the view

```
<script> 
$('#username').on('change',function(e){
var u_name=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo site_url('home/checkUserExist');?>",
data: { u_name: u_name },
dataType: "html",
success: function(msg){
                 $('#error_msg').empty();
                 $('#error_msg').append(msg);
                    },
error:function(error){
                $('#error_msg').append("There is some errors on server : " + error.error);
                    return false;
                    }
             });
});
</script>
```

Controller function

```
function checkUserExist()
{
     $u_name= strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($this->input->post('u_name'))));
     if($this->public->checkMemberExisit($u_name)==false)
     {
         echo "<p>Username Exists, Try another username</p>";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "<p>Username Available</p>";
     }

}
```

but i keep getting this error :

There is some errors on server : function (){if(h){var d=h.length;!function f(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&f(c)})}(arguments),b?e=h.length:c&&(g=d,j(c))}return this}

Can anyone tell me whats going on. it used to work before.

Comment: What is the PHP version?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
Maybe this function is the problem.

Comment: I am using XAMPP v3.2.1, is it due to php update ?

Comment: Maybe but I'm not sure about it. A sent a link in my prev. comment, and it reads that the "mysql_real_escape_string" was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed in PHP 7. Try to use "mysqli_real_escape_string". My second guess is in the "$.ajax" "error:function(error)" part. The error function first parameter is an object and not a string. Is it has error value?
"error: function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ){..."